# Unable to generate laser scanner points with the GPU using the ray plugin inside a VMware machine

Tags: ros-humble, gazebo-plugin, gazebo-11, 2dlaserscan, gpu

For some reason, I'm not able to generate laser scanner points with the GPU using the ray plugin inside a VMware machine.

Is there any reason why is not possible?